# If $R$ is not a UFD then $RS^{-1}$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

If $R$ is not a UFD then $RS^{-1}$ is not a field considering the set in $(*)$. Is this proof I did correct?

**Proof**:
Let $R$  integral domain, $P$ the set of all non-zero prime elements of $R$ and let
$$S:= \{1\}\cup\{a_1a_2\cdots a_n:a_i \in P, i=1,\dotsc ,n, n \geq 1\} \quad (*)$$
Suppose that $R$ is not a UFD. Then there exists a nonzero, noninvertible element $a \in R$ such that $a$ cannot be expressed as a finite product of primes, this implies that $a \notin S$.

Let $x \in (a)$ then for some $n \geq 1$ and $a_k,a_k'\in R$ with $k = 1,\dotsc,n$ , we have $$x = \sum_{k=1}^na_kaa_k' = a\sum_{k=1}^na_ka_k' = aw$$
where $w = \sum_{k=1}^na_ka_k'$. Let us note that $x \neq 1$ since $a$ is not invertible. Moreover, since $a$ cannot be expressed as a finite product of primes, $x$ cannot be expressed as a finite product of primes either regardless of whether $w$ can be expressed as a finite product of primes or not  and hence $x \notin S$ and so $(a)\cap S = \emptyset$. Since $(a)\cap S = \emptyset$ and $a \neq 0$, then $(\frac{a}{1})$ is a nonzero proper ideal of $RS^{-1}$ and this proves $RS^{-1}$ is not a body since there exists a nontrivial ideal. $\blacksquare$

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine. Where does the question come from?

Comment: @BillDubuque I am not entirely sure if with the arguments I offered about $x$ I can be sure that $x$ cannot be expressed as a finite product of primes. However, in principle it makes sense to me.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Is it from a textbook or did you construct it?

Comment: @BillDubuque It happens that in a book they state the following statement:
$R$ is a UFD if and only if $RS^{-1}$. $RS^{-1}$ is the ring of fractions over a commutative ring $R$ with respect to a multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$ . The sufficient condition was easy to show. All that remained was to prove the necessary condition, and that condition I tried to do by counterreciprocal.

Comment: The claim is false as stated: choose $R$ to be any non-UFD domain and $S = R\backslash 0\,$ so $\,RS^{-1}\,$ is the fraction field of $R$. Likely you are missing some hypotheses that are implicit from the context. Also the claim in your prior comment is incomplete,  iff $RS^{-1}$ is *what*?

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry. I had a confusion. $S$ is considered as I defined above in the proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry. I overlooked it. Considering the set $S$ defined in $(*)$, $R$ is a UFD if and only if $RS^{-1}$ is a field.